# Logging for public hosted zone Route53

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I'm trying to set up the logging for a public hosted zone on Route53 AWS. the template looks like this:

```
Resources:
  HostedZonePublic1:
   Type: AWS::Route53::HostedZone
   Properties:
    HostedZoneConfig:
      Comment: !Join ['', ['Hosted zone for ', !Ref 'DomainNamePublic' ]]
    Name: !Ref DomainNamePublic
    QueryLoggingConfig:
      CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn: !GetAtt Route531LogGroup.Arn

  Route531LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
     LogGroupName: Route531-AWSLogGroup
     RetentionInDays: 7
```

But when I try to launch the stack I'm getting the following message:

```
The ARN for the CloudWatch Logs log group is invalid. (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput; Request ID: 6c02db60-ef62-11e8-bce8-d14210c1b0cd)
```

Anybody an idea what could be wrong with this setup?

merci A

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue. The CloudWatch logs log group needs to be created in a specific region to be valid.

See following:

> 1. You must create the log group in the **us-east-1** region.
> 2. You must use the same AWS account to create the log group and the hosted zone that you want to configure query logging for.
> 3. When you create log groups for query logging, we recommend that you use a consistent prefix.

You can find the full documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueryLoggingConfig.html).